# How to restrict a foreign key constrain?

Tags: entity-relationship

I have the following relations between persons and addresses.

[image: Residence relations]

A `Person` has a `main_residence` attribute, which is a foreign key to the `Address` entities, and a `all_residences` attribute, which is a foreign key to the `AddressList` entities. `AddressListElement` is just a n:m-Relation helper.

Now I want to make sure, that the main residence of a person is part of all residences of that person.

Is this possible by a foreign key or do I have to write a dedicated check constraint?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy to enforce such a constraint with the following schema:

```
Person (id P, main_residence F)
Address (id P, street)
AddressList (person_id PF, address_id PF)
```

However, in your schema I believe a check constraint will be required.

Comment: This would be a PersonAddressList and not just an AddressList, because only Person could have an Address. I did not mention it in my question, but I think it is obvious that also companies may have an address.